# How to share dynamic text content of DIV or SPAN on whatsapp using jquery?

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, reactjs, whatsapp

I have been trying to share text content of DIV on *whatsapp*. But, no success yet. I do not want to share the whole document. I just want to share a part of it (I want to share contents of `showques` only).

Here is my code:

```html
<body>
    <div id="showques" style="font-size: 48px;">
    </div>
    <div id="showans" style="font-size: 48px;">
    </div>
<a href="whatsapp://send?text=#showall" data-action="share/whatsapp/share"
    tyle="background-color: green; color: ivory;font-size: 48px;height:48px;width:500px">SHARE IN WHATSAPP</a>
```

Value of `showques` gets updated from the following code:

```js
<script>
function nxtRiddle() {
        var chooserdl = [];
        for (i = 0; i < 164; i++) {
            chooserdl.push(i);
        }
        console.log(chooserdl);
        var riddleno = chooserdl[Math.floor(Math.random() * chooserdl.length)];
        console.log(riddleno);
        $('#showques').append(riddleques[riddleno]);
        $('#showans').append(riddleans[riddleno]);
        return;
    }
    nxtRiddle(0);
</script>
```

Comment: I can't understand your question. `nxtRiddle(0)` why you have 0 as argument. Function definition is not taking any argument

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is a code I got from webflow. It works!

Paste this in Inside < head > tag of the page:

```
<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Paste this in < body > tag:

```
 <div class='divblock'>
This is the first line.
This is the second line.
</div>
    <button id='button'> WHATSAPP </button>
```

Paste this in Before < /body > tag:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
(function clickMe() {
  const button = document.getElementById("button");
  var divblock = $('.divblock').text();
  button.addEventListener("click", event => {
    // Whatsapp Message on Button Click
    window.open("https://api.whatsapp.com/send?text=Show div text: " + divblock)
  });
})();
</script>
```

Output:

show div text: This is the first line. This is the second line.

Answer (score 0):

First you need to get the content of the question from `DOM`.
Then you'll have to trigger the link click event from JS and open a new tab with correct WhatsApp `url`. Hope this will help.

```js
document.getElementById("whatsAppShareButton").addEventListener('click', function(e) {
  e.preventDefault();
  var question = encodeURIComponent(document.getElementById("showques").textContent);
  window.open('whatsapp://send?text=' + question, '_blank');
});
```

```html
<div id="showques" style="font-size: 48px;">
  This is a sample question...
</div>
<div id="showans" style="font-size: 48px;">
</div>
<a href="#" id="whatsAppShareButton" data-action="share/whatsapp/share" style="background-color: green; color: ivory;font-size: 48px;height:48px;width:500px">SHARE IN WHATSAPP</a>
```